# Can't find Wacom Penabled driver in newer Ubuntu releases

Tags: drivers, wacom

I want to install Ubuntu 17.10 again in my Fujitsu Siemens Stylistic ST5112 (because my system has become really slow, and I wanted to change my HDD with a bigger one).

I have installed years ago 16.04 on this machine, and in a second time I have updated it to 17.10.

In 16.04 the integrated Wacom tablet worked perfecly (and also after the update to 17.10), but in 17.10 fresh install does not work anymore.
I tried to fetch nonfree drivers, and I also tried installing http://linuxwacom.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Input-wacom, but nothing...
(I found the same problem with Linux Mint 14 vs 18 and with newer versions of Debian)

I have the old HDD with Wacom working, and I can't find out how to make it work under another OS...

Does someone has ideas? Thanks in advice!
(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: My Wacom Intuos works perfectly in 17.10 out-of-the box. No additional drivers needed.